# unable to read config after upgrade to envoy 1.15

Tags: docker-compose, envoyproxy

I'm using Envoy docker image in docker-compose. Docker is running in Ubuntu, which is running in VM, which is running in Windows 10.

I have been using Envoy 1.14 without any problems. After upgrading image to 1.15, Envoy doesn't start and I'm getting this error:

```
unable to read file: /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

line before this one says basically the same:

```
[critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:101] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': unable to read file: /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

My docker-compose part for Envoy is simple:

```
    envoy:
        image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.15-latest
        container_name: envoy
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "~/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml:ro"
```

If I just change `envoyproxy/envoy:v1.15-latest` to `envoyproxy/envoy:v1.14-latest` and do `docker-compose down && docker-compose up`, everything works fine. Are there any special permissions for config file now? Or is it something during my upgrade process?

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause this, and can't re-create on my system, at least with the info here.  does running envoy with the mount outside docker compose show the same issue?  (Note you'll need to change the source path) `docker run -v /home/justin/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml envoyproxy/envoy:v1.15-latest`

Comment: Thank you for helping, but same result. If I run 1.14, no problems. If I just change to 1.15,  `unable to read file` error again.

Comment: filed issue https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/12747, there are more details with logs and config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in github issue: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/12747#issuecomment-677485704

Solution: change permissions for `envoy.yaml` (`chmod 777` is working fine for me).

Comment: chmod 777 is not very good practice... `chown envoy:envoy` might better